# Assistance making a cursor in tSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm sure there's a more elegant (or simply "correct") way to do what I'm trying to achieve. I believe I need to use a Cursor, but can't quite wrap my head around how to.

I have the code below to find the days left in a contract, but unless I put the 'where' clause (which basically selects a specific record), I get this error message:

> 'Subquery returned more than 1 value'

That's why I think I need a cursor; to loop through the records, and update a field with the number of days left in a contract.

Here's what I have, which works in-as-much that it returns a number.

```
DECLARE @TodaysDT date = GetDate()

DECLARE @ContractExpirationDT date =                                
    (SELECT ExprDt from CONTRACTS                                   
    WHERE ID = 274);                                                

DECLARE @DaysRemaining INT = 
(SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, @ContractExpirationDT,@TodaysDT));             

 Print @DaysRemaining;
```

This returns a correct value for a specific record ID (this case, ID 274)

How do I use a cursor to step through each record, and then update a field in each record with the `@DaysRemaining` value?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you don't need a cursor; you can just run an update without `where` clause in order to calculate remaining days for all rows.

Here is a basic example that you can use as a starting point:

```
--Create a table variable to hold test data
declare @contract table (Id int, ExprDt datetime, DaysRemaining int )

--Insert sample data
insert into @contract select 1, '20200101'  ,null
insert into @contract select 2, '20201231'  ,null
insert into @contract select 3, '20191231'  ,null
insert into @contract select 274, '20191231',null

--Save today's date inseide a variable
DECLARE @TodaysDT date = GetDate()

--Update DaysRemaining field for each record
update @contract set DaysRemaining = DATEDIFF(dd, ExprDt,@TodaysDT)

--Select records to check results
select Id, ExprDt, DaysRemaining
from @contract
```

Here is the output of this command:

[image]